# How do I find the existence of a value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

Say I wanted to check if Mango_EA existed. How would I do that in Node JS.

```
{
 "selection1": [
  {
   "name": "ClashOnGan"
  },
  {
   "name": "JoblessGarrett"
  },
  {
   "name": "FemmeFatale"
  },
  {
   "name": "Mango_EA"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON or with parsing or with node.js.

Comment: Its a json file, and Im trying to check its existence with nodeJS.

Comment: It's not a "JSON file", it's a JavaScript object. You're not trying to check its existence with node.js, you're trying to check its existence with JavaScript. You're not trying to parse the object, you're trying to access it. These "details" matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.selection1.some(x => x.name === "Mango_EA")
```

In English,

> Within the array given by `obj.selection1`, is there **some** element `x` which satisfies the condition that the `name` property of `x` is equal to `"Mango_EA"`.

Comment: What if the "obj" is a link to the file.

Comment: `obj = require('foo.json');`.